# Passing form attributes into partials

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am working on an app with NodeJS and have been able to use handlebars and partials without much trouble. I am getting to the point where I have `view` and `edit` forms for a car.

For example, after the user submits an application I have "View" and "Edit" links that go to `localhost:3000/cars/:id/view` and `localhost:3000/cars/:id/edit`, respectively.

The only difference between these two links is that the "View" page has the form with `readonly="readonly"` and the "Edit" does not have the `readonly` attribute.

**What I would like to do**

**cars/view**

```
{{ >car_form readonly=true }}
```

**cars/edit**

```
{{ >car_form readonly=false }}

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Is this possible with handlebars templates? Or is there something similar I can do to get the result I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the `readonly` option correctly, now all you need to do is use it when rendering your form.

To do that I've used a helper to render the form via JavaScript, where we can do anything we like using the [Hash Arguments](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#hash-arguments) funtionality Handlebars supports.

```js
  // Let's pretend this is the user input you're holding in Node.js
  // and want to render in your view and edit forms.
  var userInput = {
    "name": "Bob",
    "tagline": "Yep, I'm Bob!"
  };

  Handlebars.registerHelper('userForm', function(options) {
    var formOpening = options.hash.readonly ? "<form readonly=\"readonly\">" : "<form>";

    // Notice that I feed in `userInput` as the context here.
    // You may need to do this differently, depending on your setup.
    var formContents = options.fn(userInput);

    return formOpening + formContents + "</form>";
  });

  var userFormTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("userForm-template").innerHTML);
  var pageTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("page-template").innerHTML);

  Handlebars.registerPartial('userForm', userFormTemplate);

  document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML = pageTemplate();
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>

<script id="page-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h2>View</h2>
  {{> userForm readonly=true}}

  <h2>Edit</h2>
  {{> userForm readonly=false}}
</script>

<script id="userForm-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#userForm readonly=readonly}}
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{name}}" />
    <input type="text" name="tagline" value="{{tagline}}" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  {{/userForm}}
</script>

<script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
```

In the above snippet, the `readonly="readonly"` attribute is being added to the form beneath the "View" heading.

Note that on my browser, this does not actually make the form read-only - I'm not sure if you've got another library or something to handle that?